# discord.js Sending data from a json file into a single message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello I would like to make a command in which you can see who is online.
For this I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "796442577058398258": {
    "online": "true"
  }
  "880126271881904179": {
    "online": "true"
  }

}
```

And this is the command I have

```
command(client, 'status', (message) => {
    const path = require('path');

    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'idList.json'))
    let statusID = JSON.parse(rawdata)

    for (var statusIDs in statusID) {
        console.log(statusIDs)
    }

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("GREEN")
    .setTitle('LSPD Anmelde Liste')
    .setDescription(`<@${statusIDs}>`)
    .setFooter(`Status`).setTimestamp()
    message.reply(embed)
})
```

But when I test the command then the console says:

```
796442577058398258
880126271881904179
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
796442577058398258, 880126271881904179
```

Comment: Is that even valid JSON...?

Comment: Yes it is. I can read it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
var message  
for (var statusID in statusIDs) {
        message = message + " " + statusIDs
}
console.log(message)
```

This just appends the variable to a string and then prints the whole string.

You can also try this:

```
var message  
for (var statusID in statusIDs) {
    if(StatusIDs.indexOf(StatusID)==0){
        message = message + statusID
    }else{
        message = message + ", " + statusID
    }
 }
    console.log(message)
```

The second example will also format the message as requested in your code example. I think you confused StatusIDs and StatusID in your code so i switched it around in my example code.